# Stange return type using implicit in Scala

Tags: scala

I can't understand. why each function have different return type using type constraint or not.

First i did make function `inv` like below, and it' return type is Int

```
implicit val x = 10
def inv[A](a: A)(implicit ev: Int) = ev
inv(1) // it return 10

// res0: Int = 10
```

Then i did make function `inv2` with type constraints like below, and it'  return type is Function1

```
def inv2[A](a: A)(implicit ev: Int <:< Int) = ev
inv2(1)

// res2: <:<[Int,Int] = <function1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inv2`'s return type is inferred as `<:<[Int,Int]` - as expected.

However, the runtime type of the returned value is `Int => Int`. That's because `<:<` *is* a function.

```
sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable
```

And calling `toString` on a function results in `<function1>` being printed.